# How to determine if file has changed on the S3 bucket from a mobile client (e.g. iOS)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-management

Is it possible to use **AWSS3TransferManager** or an alternative class to determine if a file has changed on the s3 server before downloading it?

Ideally I'd like to have some sort of automatic function that takes into account automatically the following:

- File size
- File type
- File name

or:

- File content data analysis (some sort of signature based on bit content)

**Alternatively:**

I see that it is possible to get the [modification date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746760/how-do-i-get-the-s3-keys-created-date-with-boto) for an **s3 bucket**, however I am not sure how this works in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the file like the `AWSS3TransferManager download` method, you can use the alternative class [`AWSS3GetObjectRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3GetObjectRequest.html) / [`AWSS3GetObjectOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3GetObjectOutput.html).

If you do **not** want to download the file, you can use [`AWSS3HeadObjectRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3HeadObjectRequest.html) / [`AWSS3HeadObjectOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSS3HeadObjectOutput.html) that will return the object's metadata or "head" of the file.

The value: `lastModified` will be in the `AWSS3...ObjectOutput` value for both class responses.