# How to find hbase table creation date

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

Is there a way to find the creation date or timestamp of a HBase table.
We have `desc <table>` in `Hive` that will give the table creation information. I am curious to know if there is any HBase command to get the metadata information? 
The `describe 'table'` does not provide any time or date information.

Answer (score 2):

Hbase data are located in HDFS and there is no direct way to do that. Check `hbase.rootdir` and run `hadoop fs -ls -R | grep yourtable` to see when is created or modified(in timestamp).

Comment: If the file system is S3, i have to change the command. So I am looking for a generic hbase command.

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy you can get date from S3. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27751384/1780704

Comment: I can get the data from S3 which is doable, but that is not my concern. I am looking for a HBase client that can do the job instead of getting the table information from HDFS or S3.

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy check this command: `describe formatted <your_table_name>;`

Comment: @AlexRajKaliamoorthy Only way is to get FileStatus like I said. There is no documented way to do that.