# How to Find out created date of file in s3 storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

We have multiple SRT files & unable to find out creation date of file where we can able to see only modified date. Is there any possibility to check both creation & modified date of s3 storage file using lambda function?

Comment: It's the same thing. It is not possible to modify an object in Amazon S3, so the `LastModifiedDate` is also the create date. Why do they call it that? Well, you can overwrite an object with a new object, which sort of makes it 'modified', I guess.

Comment: Yes. Its showing new modified date once file changed

Comment: You can also use the boto3 `list_object_versions` function to get all versions of an object. You might be able to find the first one, i.e. the createdAt there.

Comment: Versioning is not enabled yet. so any other way to see old object_versions?

Comment: Previous versions of objects are only available after Versioning is activated. You will be charged for _all_ versions of objects that are stored.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the modified date changes if you move a file from one folder to another, for example from a to process folder into an archive folder. shouldnt there be a way to retain that initial create date?

Answer (score 0):

As John commented and as it is said in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52407395/19518308

> when we use the term creation date, it is synonymous with the term
> last modified date.

So you just need use the Last Modified Date, and apparently it is the only option you got.